# Add linkToItem using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jslink, hyperlink

I am trying to add a hyperlink on a column which leads to the edit item menu. I know that it is possible to do this with SharePoint Designer, however as there is no more support for it, I would love to do it with javascript.

Comment: WHich sharepoint version are you using?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2016

Comment: Why don't you use the column "edit" in the list view? -which shows an edit icon (pencil) on the page.